# About UNION and FILTER NOT EXISTS in SPARQL (OpenRDF 2.8.0)

Tags: sparql, sesame

I learnt some semantic technologies, including RDF and SPARQL, a few years ago, then I didn't have chances to work with them for some time. Now I've started a new project which uses OpenRDF 2.8.0 as a semantic store and I'm resuming my knowledge, even though I have some forgotten things to recover.

In particular, in the past days I had some troubles in correctly undestanding the FILTER NOT EXIST construct in SPARQL.

Problem: I have a semantic store imported from DbTune.org (music ontologies). A `mo:MusicArtist`, intended as `foaf:maker` of a `mo:Track`, can be present in four scenarios (I'm only listing relevant statements):

```
    <http://dbtune.org/musicbrainz/resource/artist/013c8e5b-d72a-4cd3-8dee-6c64d6125823> a mo:MusicArtist ;
        vocab:artist_type "1"^^xs:short ;
        rdfs:label "Edvard Grieg" .

    <http://dbtune.org/musicbrainz/resource/artist/032df978-9130-490e-8857-0c9ef231fae8> a mo:MusicArtist ;
        vocab:artist_type "2"^^xs:short ;
        rel:collaboratesWith <http://dbtune.org/musicbrainz/resource/artist/3db5dfb1-1b91-4038-8268-ae04d15b6a3e> , <http://dbtune.org/musicbrainz/resource/artist/d78afc01-f918-440c-89fc-9d546a3ba4ac> ;
        rdfs:label "Doris Day & Howard Keel".

    <http://dbtune.org/musicbrainz/resource/artist/1645f335-2367-427d-8e2d-ad206946a8eb> a mo:MusicArtist ;
        vocab:artist_type "2"^^xs:short ;
        rdfs:label "Pat Metheny & Anna Maria Jopek".

    <http://dbtune.org/musicbrainz/resource/artist/12822d4f-4607-4f1d-ab16-d6bacc27cafe> a mo:MusicArtist ;
        rdfs:label "René Marie".
```

From what I understand, the `vocab:artist_type` is `1` for single artists (example #1) and `2` for groups of collaborations (examples #2 and #3). In this case, there might a few `rel:collaboratesWith` statements that point to the description of the single members of the group or collaboration (example #2). In some cases, the `vocab:artist_type` statement is missing (example #4).

Now I want to extract all the artists as single entities, where possibile. I mean, I don't want to retrieve example #2, because I will get "Doris Day" and "Howard Keel" separately. I have to retrieve example #3 "Pat Metheny & Anna Maria Jopek" because I can't do anything else. Of course, I also want to retrieve "René Marie".

I've solved the problem in a satisfactory way with this SPARQL:

```
    SELECT *
    WHERE  
      { 
        ?artist     a           mo:MusicArtist. 
        ?artist     rdfs:label  ?label. 

        MINUS 
          {
            ?artist     vocab:artist_type       "2"^^xs:short.
            ?artist     rel:collaboratesWith    ?any1 .
          }
      } 
    ORDER BY ?label
```

It makes sense and it looks like it's readable ("retrieve all `mo:MusicArtist` items minus those that are collaborations with individual members listed").

I didn't find the solution immediately. I first thought of putting together the three separate cases, with `UNION`:

```
    SELECT *
    WHERE  
      { 
        ?artist       a                 mo:MusicArtist. 
        ?artist       rdfs:label        ?label. 
    # Single artists
          {
            ?artist     vocab:artist_type       "1"^^xs:short.
          }
        UNION
    # Groups for which there is no defined collaboration with single persons
          {
            ?artist     vocab:artist_type       "2"^^xs:short.
            FILTER NOT EXISTS 
              {
                ?artist     rel:collaboratesWith    ?any1 
              }
          }
        UNION
    # Some artists don't have this attribute
          {
            FILTER NOT EXISTS 
              {
                ?artist     vocab:artist_type       ?any2
              }
          }
      } 
    ORDER BY ?label
```

I found that the third `UNION` statements, the ones which should add `mo:MusicArtist` items without a `vocab:artist_type`, didn't worked. That is, they didn't find the items such as "René Marie".

While I'm satisfied with the shortest solution I found with `MINUS`, I'm not ok with the fact that I don't understand why the older solution didn't work. Clearly I'm missing some point with `FILTER NOT EXISTS` that could be useful for some other case.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: One of your comments says "Groups for which there is no defined collaboration with single persons"---is there supposed to be any check that the collaborator (the value of ?any1) is actually a single person, i.e., not a group?

Comment: Joshua, good question. I haven't seen groups related to groups in the data related to my music collection, but of course I didn't explore the whole repository. I think it doesn't matter. The idea is that if there is a rel:collaborationWith it could be anything, eventually a chain of collaborations, there will be a final item which is no more related to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run the following query, I get the results that it sounds like you're looking for:

```sql
select distinct ?label where {
  ?artist a mo:MusicArtist ;
          rdfs:label ?label .

  #-- artists with type 1
  {
    ?artist vocab:artist_type "1"^^xs:short
  }
  #-- artists with no type
  union {
    filter not exists { 
      ?artist vocab:artist_type ?type
    }
  }
  #-- artists with type 2 that have no
  #-- collaborators
  union {
    ?artist vocab:artist_type "2"^^xs:short
    filter not exists {
      ?artist rel:collaboratesWith ?another
    }
  }
}
```

```
------------------------------------
| label                            |
====================================
| "René Marie"                     |
| "Pat Metheny & Anna Maria Jopek" |
| "Edvard Grieg"                   |
------------------------------------
```

I'm not whether I see where this essentially differs from yours, though.  I do think that you could clean this query up a bit though. You can use **optional** and **values** to specify that the type is optional, but if present must be 1 or 2.  Then you can add a filter that requires that when the value is 2, there is no collaborator.

```sql
select ?label where {
  #-- get an artist and their label
  ?artist a mo:MusicArtist ;
          rdfs:label ?label .

  #-- and optionally their type, if it is
  #-- "1"^^xs:short or "2"^^xs:short
  optional {
    values ?type { "1"^^xs:short "2"^^xs:short }
    ?artist vocab:artist_type ?type
  }

  #-- if ?type is "2"^^xs:short, then ?artist
  #-- must not collaborate with anyone.
  filter ( !sameTerm(?type,"2"^^xs:short)
        || not exists { ?artist rel:collaboratesWith ?anyone })
}
```

```
------------------------------------
| label                            |
====================================
| "René Marie"                     |
| "Pat Metheny & Anna Maria Jopek" |
| "Edvard Grieg"                   |
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm studying it. By the way: I've not considered performance issues yet. I suppose that different queries that produce the same results can perform in different ways. Years ago I was aware of some things to avoid, but after such a long time I think things could have been changed. Is there any construct which is known to be slow? Of course I'm referring to the OpenRDF implementation.

Comment: @FabrizioGiudici I think that the state of query optimization for SPARQL is not quite as advanced as some relational databases, and there's a bit more variation between systems, too. Personally, I'd hold off on worrying too much about performance until you know whether something is a bottleneck or not.